# How to build jfreechart-1.0.19 from sources?

Tags: java, ant, jfreechart

I'm trying to build this project:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch v1.0.19 https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart.git
```

With "mvn install" command, there are following errors:

```
Failed tests:   testFifteenMinIncludedAndExcludedSegments(org.jfree.chart.axis.SegmentedTimelineTest)
  testFifteenMinSegmentedTimeline(org.jfree.chart.axis.SegmentedTimelineTest): expected:<-2208956400000> but was:<-2208967200000>
  testMondayThroughFridaySegmentedTimeline(org.jfree.chart.axis.SegmentedTimelineTest): expected:<-2208988800000> but was:<-2208999600000>
  testFindDomainBounds(org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollectionTest): expected:<1.199142E12> but was:<1.1991348E12>
```

Then I trying to build with ANT script

```
cd ant
ant
```

And I got `jfreechart-1.0.19-bundle.jar` 8M weight which is very different from MAVEN's jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.19/ . Please tell me how to build  [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) version 1.0.19 form sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building from the original source distribution found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/1.%20JFreeChart/1.0.19/). Verify the checksum, unzip the file and build with `ant`:

```
$ java -version
java version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS…
$ md5 jfreechart-1.0.19.zip 
MD5 (jfreechart-1.0.19.zip) = 69a5c88439566ac9d7e74cf34c69b7e0
$ unzip -qq jfreechart-1.0.19.zip 
$ pushd jfreechart-1.0.19
$ pushd ant ; ant ; popd
…
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

For `lib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar`, I get a size of `1_565_109` bytes, comparable  to the `1_565_065` bytes seen [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.19/). You also need `jcommon-1.0.23.jar`, included in the `lib` directory and found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/3.%20JCommon/1.0.23/).

**Addendum**: Starting from a clone of the [repository](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart), a similar approach also works, producing a `1_565_051` byte JAR in `lib` and an 8M `jfreechart-1.0.19-bundle.jar`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart.git jfreechart
$ pushd jfreechart
$ git fetch --tags
$ git tag --list
…
v1.0.19
…
$ git checkout v1.0.19
Note: switching to 'v1.0.19'…
$ pushd ant ; ant ; popd
…
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
$ git checkout master
$ git status
…
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    jfreechart-1.0.19-bundle.jar
    jfreechart-1.0.19-javadocs.zip
    jfreechart-1.0.19.tar.gz
    jfreechart-1.0.19.zip
    lib/
 …
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried something similar to your approach. I see the 8M bundle, as well as the `lib` files. More above.