# Create jfreechart-1.5.3 JAR from source code

Tags: java, linux, jar, jfreechart

My program is trying to upgrade from an old version of JFreeChart, we are using [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) to compile and have JFreeChart imported as a .jar file. I am trying to get the new `jfreechart-1.5.3` source (I cannot find a jar on their website) into a working .jar file by using:

```
jar cf jfreechart.jar jfreechart-1.5.3/src
```

When trying to compile with the new .jar file. I get the error that "package org.jfree.chart" does not exist. How do I update my program with a .jar file of the newest JFreeChart version?

Answer (score 2):

As illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68810025/230513), you can clone the repository, check out the branch with the desired tag and use [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) to build the release JARs. See also [*Migration from JFreeChart 1.0.x*](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart#migration)

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart.git jfreechart
$ pushd jfreechart
$ git fetch --tags
$ git tag --list
…
v1.5.3
$ git checkout v1.5.3
Note: switching to 'v1.5.3'.
…
$ mvn -P release package
…
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
…
$ ls -1 target/jfreechart-1.5.3*
target/jfreechart-1.5.3-javadoc.jar
target/jfreechart-1.5.3-sources.jar
target/jfreechart-1.5.3.jar
```

Alternatively, download the desired JARs directly from the corresponding *mvnrepository* directory:

v1.5.2: [*mvnrepository*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart/1.5.2) > [directory](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jfree/jfreechart/1.5.2/).
v1.5.3: [*mvnrepository*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart/1.5.3) > [directory](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jfree/jfreechart/1.5.3/).
v1.5.4: [*mvnrepository*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart/1.5.4) > [directory](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jfree/jfreechart/1.5.4/).