# Change the font size of the y-axis and x-axis values

Tags: java, swt, jfreechart

In the following code, I want to reduce the font size of the y-axis and x-axis values.

[image]

I searched and found these code:

suppose you want to reduce the font size of number axis use the following code:

```
Font nwfont=new Font("Arial",0,7);
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setTickLabelFont(nwfont);
```

suppose you want to reduce the font size of CategoryAxis use the following code:

```
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(nwfont);
```

but unfortunately, the size of the axes did not decrease.
Did I do something wrong?

this sample code:

```
 public class NegativeExpPlot {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new NegativeExpPlot()::display);
        }

        private void display() {
            int nData = 100;
            Random r = new Random(nData);
            XYSeries ds1 = new XYSeries("rand");
            for (int i = 0; i < nData; i++) {
                ds1.add(r.nextDouble(), r.nextDouble() / 1000);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nData; i++) {
                ds1.add(r.nextDouble(), r.nextDouble() * 1000);
            }
            LogAxis logAxis = new LogAxis("log");
            XYPlot p = new XYPlot(new XYSeriesCollection(ds1), new NumberAxis(),
                logAxis, new XYLineAndShapeRenderer());
            logAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new DecimalFormat("0.0E0"));
            Font nwfont=new Font("Arial",0,1);
            logAxis.setTickLabelFont(nwfont);
            JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(p);
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Log Axis");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.add(new ChartPanel(chart));
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
            NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) p.getRangeAxis();
            rangeAxis.setTickLabelFont(nwfont);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, reported in [issue #98](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/issues/98): *`setTickLabelFont` is not respected for `LogAxis` if `setNumberFormatOverride` is used*. It is fixed in branch [v1.5.x](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/tree/v1.5.x). You can omit the override, use the workaround in the bug report, or build `jfreechart-1.5.4-SNAPSHOT.jar`, illustrated, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653678/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.LogAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70758061/230513 */
public class ExpoTest {

    private static final int N = 100;
    private static final Font FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 16);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new ExpoTest()::display);
    }

    private void display() {
        Random r = new Random();
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("rand");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            series.add(r.nextDouble(), r.nextDouble() / 1000);
        }
        NumberAxis domainAxis = new NumberAxis();
        domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(FONT);
        LogAxis rangeAxis = new LogAxis("log");
        rangeAxis.setTickLabelFont(FONT);
        rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new DecimalFormat("0.0E0"));
        XYPlot p = new XYPlot(new XYSeriesCollection(series), domainAxis,
            rangeAxis, new XYLineAndShapeRenderer());
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(p);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Log Axis");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(chart));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome.