# Not able to import the classes with jar file for jfreechart

Tags: java, eclipse, jfreechart

I am trying to use jfreechart - release jfreechart-1.0-2.19 available on the website https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/download.html

IDE: Eclipse on Mac

Regular java project.

The import fails for pretty much everything in the jar files I tried to add from jfree library.

[image: Eclipse - jfreechart import failure]

Added the jar files available under jfreechart-1.0-2.19->lib folder to the project on Eclipse with following steps:

Right Click on Project-> BuildPath-> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars
and added all files in the library folder mentioned above.

Not sure what else can be done and I am unable to resolve.

Comment: [tag:jfreechart] v1.5.4 is current; more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653678/230513).

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_) or [in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules) and move the other code into packages. If this does not help, in the _Package Explorer_ expand the `jfreechart-1.0.19.jar` node to show whether there is a `org.jfree.chart` package.

Comment: Aside: For version 1.0.19, you only need `jfreechart` and `jcommon`, e.g. `java -cp jfreechart-1.0.19.jar:jcommon-1.0.23.jar org.jfree.chart.demo.BarChartDemo1`.