# JavaFreeChart add Library - .jar not found

Tags: java, installation, jar, libraries, jfreechart

Hi I'm having trouble adding the JFreeChart library. After I download it from https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/releases/tag/v1.5.4 and decompress it, I can't find the .jar file.
[image]

However, even in the lib library folder there's a JavaScript file but I don't know if there's a way to add the library with these files, what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I’d recommend not managing dependencies by hand. If you **must** make more work for yourself consider getting the artifacts from the Maven repo, but you’ll need to get its transitive dependencies as well. It’s more work than necessary but you do you 

Comment: You downloaded source code. If you need a jar library, you will need to build it with Maven or alternatively, if you want to use JFreeChart in a Maven project, add the dependency to your pom. You can see it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart/1.5.4)

Comment: Download from the [tag:maven] repository or build from source using [tag:maven]; possible duplicate of [_Create jfreechart-1.5.3 JAR from source code_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653678/230513).

Comment: Thank you, building it from source worked 